# Check many times two columns SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a table that contains

- ID
- Update number

---

a user have a list of the ids that he downloaded already and their update number.
i want to give the user only the necessary ids to download each time (which are new ids - that he didn't yet download or ids that got update).
I want to make a query that bring me this.
lets say for the example that the user has downloaded 3 ids.

- First: ID = 1, Update = 0;
- Second: ID = 2, Update = 0;
- Third: ID = 3, Update = 0;

so now me in the server want to update an id so the user will download it again so i put the update number of the first id to 1 (and if it was 1 I put it to 2 or 3 and more and more).

I need the query that the user will send to the server in order to only get the necessary ids.

I tried this query:

```
SELECT * FROM idtable WHERE (id <> 1 AND update <> 0) AND (id <> 2 AND update <> 0) AND (id <> 3 AND update <> 0)
```

but this is not valid. (If you are looking on the example it should return only id number 1 because I updated it from the server).

Please help me!!

Comment: really cant tell what your asking.

Comment: if this is downloads per user, shouldn't it have a key in the table to join them?

Comment: In your example, you are updating record for ID 1, so you already know the id. you can query `select * from idtable where id = 1`. The query you wrote doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to filter out packages that alredy have is same version as the database, then you could use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM idtable 
WHERE
    CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN IF(update > 0, TRUE, FALSE)
        WHEN 2 THEN IF(update > 0, TRUE, FALSE)
        WHEN 3 THEN IF(update > 0, TRUE, FALSE)
        ELSE TRUE
    END
```

Comment: You are the best!! checking this and will put answer if its true

Comment: Assuming 1,2,3 is a representation of "all records", then you've just written a fancy version of my first query...

Comment: if id 3 is on its 4th update, you can update that row to: WHEN 3 THEN IF(update > 4, TRUE, FALSE)

Comment: are you sure this is valid form? its not letting me use this and it gives an error that say that the query is invalid

Comment: Sorry, "ELSE THEN" should be just "ELSE"

Answer (score 0):

The query to get the IDs to download is simply

```
SELECT *
  FROM idtable
 WHERE update > 0
```

The query assumes that you simply toggle update column to 1 when there's something new to update.

Now, if your question is about how to *update* the table such that it will turn the next non-update row to 1, then it's a different kettle of fish.

---

If you're updating the "update" (I'm sure it's a proper name) column to a version number, then your table structure should be something like:

```
user_id int
version int
downloaded_version int
```

So that when the user downloads a version, you update `downloaded_version` to match the `version` they just updated.  Next time around, you update `version` to `version+1`.
And the query to look for updates becomes:

```
SELECT *
  FROM idtable
 WHERE user_id = <userid>
   AND version > downloaded_version
```

Comment: - Every id has different update level (it can be 1 or 2 or 3 or more)

Comment: its not about updating but about checking two columns togther many times.. like in programming language when you do: if((a == 2 && u == 0) || (a == 3 && u == 1) || (a==4 && u == 0))

Comment: I think you need programming help more than SQL help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're incrementing update numbers, try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM idtable
WHERE (
    (id = 1 AND update > 0) OR
    (id = 2 AND update > 0) OR
    (id = 3 AND update > 0)
)
```

If your users have more than a couple IDs downloaded, you can consider creating another table with:

- userID
- ID
- Update number

This way you could get all updates without adding multiple OR statements:

```
SELECT it.* FROM idtable it, userdownload ud WHERE ud.userID = it.id and ud.id = it.id and ud.update < it.update
```

Comment: the first query is good for me but its not valid, this is close to the query i wrote but just not valid query